# i want to show only 80% row of total number of rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

```
    GroupNo   Commodity    AuctionRate    Quantity  Mandi Grade
     1         8            25000          5000      2      1
     1         8            5555           5000      2      1
     1         8            6000           2000      2      1
     2         8            4000           500       2      3
     1         8            6000           500       2      1
     1         8            5000           500       2      1
     1         8            77777          500       2      1
     1         8            22222          200       2      1
     1         8            55555          100       2      1
     1         8            100            100       2      1
```

Here I get this table by using Following Query

```
    select 

    dense_rank() over (order by AD."Commodity",AD."Mandi",AD."Grade") as "GroupNo"
    ,AD."Commodity"
    ,AD."AuctionRate"
    ,AD."Quntity"
    ,AD."Mandi"
    ,AD."Grade"


    from "AuctionDetails" AD

    order by  AD."Quntity" desc
```

Now I have a "GroupNo" for each group of record.

Now i want to do summation of "AuctionRate" and "Quantity" of only 80% record which have same group NUmber

In our Example there are 9 rows with groupNo "1" and only 1 row  with groupNo "2".

Now 80% of 9 is around 7 and 80% of 1 is around 1.

So I want sum of "AuctionRate" and "Quantity" of only top 7 rows which have groupno "1" and sum of 1 row which have groupno "2" as well

A desired result is shown below

```
    GroupNo   Commodity    AuctionRate    Quantity  Mandi Grade
     1         8            147554         13700     2      1
     2         8            4000           500       2      3
```

Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Hint: having (number / count) >= .8.

Comment: Please explain.......

Comment: Look up thte `having` clause.

Comment: Postgres doc for the [HAVING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't look very neat, but here it is:

```
WITH Main AS (
  SELECT  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AD.Commodity, AD.Mandi, AD.Grade) AS GroupNo
        , AD.Commodity
        , AD.AuctionRate
        , AD.Quantity
        , AD.Mandi
        , AD.Grade
  FROM AuctionDetails AS AD
  ORDER BY AD.Quantity DESC
)
SELECT  q.GroupNo
      , q.Commodity AS Commodity
      , SUM(q.AuctionRate) AS AuctionRate
      , SUM(q.Quantity) AS Quantity
      , q.Mandi
      , q.Grade 
FROM
(
  SELECT  Main.*
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Main.GroupNo ORDER BY Main.Quantity DESC) AS RowNum
        , Counter.Total
    FROM Main
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Main.GroupNo, COUNT(*) AS Total
        FROM Main
        GROUP BY Main.GroupNo
    ) AS Counter
  ON Main.GroupNo = Counter.GroupNo
) AS q
WHERE q.RowNum <= CAST(q.Total * 0.8 AS INT)
GROUP BY q.GroupNo, q.Commodity, q.Mandi, q.Grade
```

Since you don't have `SELECT TOP 80 PERCENT` in PostgreSQL, and, moreover, since you need to round it up (7 of 9 and 1 of 1), you should do it manually. That's why it is necessary to join table with `SELECT COUNT(*)` from itself.

Deep nesting can't be avoided because you can't use `ROW_NUMBER()` in `WHERE`-clause.

Please, check out [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/200d9/6) for more details. First query shows the main idea: we get row's number inside the group and total amount of elements inside the group. When we have them, we can do the magic.